# APNS play sound until app is opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on APNS there's an issue which I'm facing I've read some questions. In my app when an notification is received. I want to play a sound until app is opened by user. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: AFAIK this can´t be achieved and that´s a good thing.

Comment: @dan , but in some cases like mine, it's needed, so there's any workabout ?

Comment: You may want it, but unless the user signs up for it, it's not needed.

Comment: @Avi so, I have to show some alert or something ?

Comment: I didn't mean there's a technical solution.  I meant that your wants do not translate into user needs, no matter how strongly you want them to.

Comment: @Avi okay, i thought we might have something like in android :(

Comment: Different philosophies.  Android is designed for the programmer, iOS is designed for the user.

Answer (score 1):

> Custom sounds must be under 30 seconds when played. If a custom sound
>   is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.

Based on the documentation, the custom sound must be under 30 seconds. Therefore, there is no guarantee that it will stop playing until the application is opened. Here is the reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6

Comment: does that mean I can play default sound for more than 30 sec ?

Comment: No.  The default sound is a simple tone/beep.  You can't replay the sound, no matter what the sound is.

Comment: Do you see the docs says it's under 30 seconds? Otherwise, system sound will played instead. And system sound is just a simple tone.

Comment: @LucasHuang yes I did, I though maybe for 30 sec it played custom sound and then default sound.